# Битрикс: Фильтрация по активности в bitrix:catalog?

Tags: php, битрикс, filter

Для комплексного компонента каталог использую фильтр:

`"FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter"`

Всё работает корректно, за исключением "ACTIVE". В независимости от значения, выводятся только активные элементы.

В чем может быть причина? Может ли быть прописан ещё где-то некий фильтр для компонента? Если да, то обычно где они прописываются?

Фильтр:
`$arrFilter = array("!CATALOG_PRICE_".$arPrices['IDS'][0]=>false,"ACTIVE"=>"");`

Код вызова компонента:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog", 
    "catalog1", 
    array(
        "ACTION_VARIABLE" => "action",
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "ADD_PICT_PROP" => "MORE_PHOTO",
        "ADD_PROPERTIES_TO_BASKET" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "ADD_SECTION_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "ALSO_BUY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "20",
        "ALSO_BUY_MIN_BUYES" => "1",
        "BASKET_URL" => "/personal/cart/",
        "BIG_DATA_RCM_TYPE" => "bestsell",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "Y",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "COMMON_ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
        "COMMON_SHOW_CLOSE_POPUP" => "Y",
        "COMPARE_ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
        "COMPARE_ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "asc",
        "COMPARE_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "NAME",
            1 => "SORT",
            2 => "PREVIEW_TEXT",
            3 => "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
            4 => "DETAIL_TEXT",
            5 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
            6 => "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM",
            7 => "SHOW_COUNTER",
            8 => "",
        ),
        "COMPARE_NAME" => "CATALOG_COMPARE_LIST",
        "COMPARE_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "COMPARE_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "ARTNUMBER",
            1 => "COLOR_REF",
            2 => "SIZES_SHOES",
            3 => "SIZES_CLOTHES",
            4 => "",
        ),
        "COMPARE_POSITION" => "top left",
        "COMPARE_POSITION_FIXED" => "N",
        "COMPARE_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "ARTNUMBER",
            1 => "NEWPRODUCT",
            2 => "SALELEADER",
            3 => "COLOR",
            4 => "MATERIAL",
            5 => "MANUFACTURER",
            6 => "SPECIALOFFER",
            7 => "BRAND_REF",
            8 => "",
        ),
        "COMPATIBLE_MODE" => "Y",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "catalog1",
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_MODE" => "A",
        "COMPOSITE_FRAME_TYPE" => "AUTO",
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
        "CURRENCY_ID" => "RUB",
        "DETAIL_ADD_DETAIL_TO_SLIDER" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => array(
            0 => "BUY",
        ),
        "DETAIL_BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
        "DETAIL_BLOG_EMAIL_NOTIFY" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_BLOG_URL" => "catalog_comments",
        "DETAIL_BLOG_USE" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_BRAND_PROP_CODE" => array(
            0 => "BRAND_REF",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_BRAND_USE" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "DETAIL_CHECK_SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "N",
        "DETAIL_DETAIL_PICTURE_MODE" => "POPUP",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT_MODE" => "E",
        "DETAIL_FB_APP_ID" => "",
        "DETAIL_FB_USE" => "N",
        "DETAIL_META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "DETAIL_META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "DETAIL_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "NAME",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "ARTNUMBER",
            1 => "COLOR_REF",
            2 => "SIZES_SHOES",
            3 => "SIZES_CLOTHES",
            4 => "MORE_PHOTO",
            5 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "VENTILYATSIYA_BEZ_NAGREVA",
            1 => "DETEKTSIYA_PO_OPTICHESKOY_PLOTNOSTI",
            ..............Etc
        ),
        "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
        "DETAIL_SET_VIEWED_IN_COMPONENT" => "N",
        "DETAIL_SHOW_BASIS_PRICE" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_SHOW_MAX_QUANTITY" => "N",
        "DETAIL_STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
        "DETAIL_USE_COMMENTS" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_USE_VOTE_RATING" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_VK_API_ID" => "API_ID",
        "DETAIL_VK_USE" => "N",
        "DETAIL_VOTE_DISPLAY_AS_RATING" => "rating",
        "DISABLE_INIT_JS_IN_COMPONENT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_SELECT_BOX" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD2" => "active_from",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD_BOX" => "name",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD_BOX2" => "id",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => "desc",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER_BOX" => "asc",
        "ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER_BOX2" => "desc",
        "FIELDS" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "FILTER_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
        "FILTER_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
            1 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
            2 => "",
        ),
        "FILTER_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "FILTER_PRICE_CODE" => array(
        ),
        "FILTER_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "VERTICAL",
        "FORUM_ID" => "1",
        "GIFTS_DETAIL_BLOCK_TITLE" => "Выберите один из подарков",
        "GIFTS_DETAIL_HIDE_BLOCK_TITLE" => "N",
        "GIFTS_DETAIL_PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
        "GIFTS_DETAIL_TEXT_LABEL_GIFT" => "Подарок",
        "GIFTS_MAIN_PRODUCT_DETAIL_BLOCK_TITLE" => "Выберите один из товаров, чтобы получить подарок",
        "GIFTS_MAIN_PRODUCT_DETAIL_HIDE_BLOCK_TITLE" => "N",
        "GIFTS_MAIN_PRODUCT_DETAIL_PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
        "GIFTS_MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Выбрать",
        "GIFTS_SECTION_LIST_BLOCK_TITLE" => "Подарки к товарам этого раздела",
        "GIFTS_SECTION_LIST_HIDE_BLOCK_TITLE" => "N",
        "GIFTS_SECTION_LIST_PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
        "GIFTS_SECTION_LIST_TEXT_LABEL_GIFT" => "Подарок",
        "GIFTS_SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "Y",
        "GIFTS_SHOW_IMAGE" => "Y",
        "GIFTS_SHOW_NAME" => "Y",
        "GIFTS_SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "Y",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Y",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE_OFFERS" => "Y",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "2",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y",
        "LABEL_PROP" => "-",
        "LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "3",
        "LINK_ELEMENTS_URL" => "link.php?PARENT_ELEMENT_ID=#ELEMENT_ID#",
        "LINK_IBLOCK_ID" => "2",
        "LINK_IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "LINK_PROPERTY_SID" => "RECOMMEND",
        "LIST_BROWSER_TITLE" => "UF_BROWSER_TITLE",
        "LIST_META_DESCRIPTION" => "UF_META_DESCRIPTION",
        "LIST_META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "LIST_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "NAME",
            1 => "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
            2 => "DETAIL_PICTURE",
            3 => "SHOW_COUNTER",
            4 => "",
        ),
        "LIST_OFFERS_LIMIT" => "0",
        "LIST_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "VENTILYATSIYA_BEZ_NAGREVA",
            1 => "DETEKTSIYA_PO_OPTICHESKOY_PLOTNOSTI",
            ...............Etc
        ),
        "MAIN_TITLE" => "Наличие на складах",
        "MESSAGES_PER_PAGE" => "10",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "MESS_BTN_ADD_TO_BASKET" => "В корзину",
        "MESS_BTN_BUY" => "Купить",
        "MESS_BTN_COMPARE" => "Сравнение",
        "MESS_BTN_DETAIL" => "Подробнее",
        "MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "Нет в наличии",
        "MIN_AMOUNT" => "10",
        "OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES" => array(
            0 => "COLOR_REF",
            1 => "SIZES_SHOES",
            2 => "SIZES_CLOTHES",
        ),
        "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => "sort",
        "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "id",
        "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" => "desc",
        "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "desc",
        "OFFER_ADD_PICT_PROP" => "MORE_PHOTO",
        "OFFER_TREE_PROPS" => array(
            0 => "COLOR_REF",
            1 => "SIZES_SHOES",
            2 => "SIZES_CLOTHES",
        ),
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "pagi",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Товары",
        "PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "48",
        "PARTIAL_PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => "N",
        "PATH_TO_SMILE" => "/bitrix/images/forum/smile/",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(
            0 => "Розница",
        ),
        "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
        "PRICE_VAT_SHOW_VALUE" => "N",
        "PRODUCT_DISPLAY_MODE" => "Y",
        "PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE" => "id",
        "PRODUCT_PROPERTIES" => array(
        ),
        "PRODUCT_PROPS_VARIABLE" => "prop",
        "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE" => "quantity",
        "QUANTITY_FLOAT" => "N",
        "REVIEW_AJAX_POST" => "Y",
        "SECTIONS_SHOW_PARENT_NAME" => "Y",
        "SECTIONS_VIEW_MODE" => "LIST",
        "SECTION_ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
        "SECTION_BACKGROUND_IMAGE" => "-",
        "SECTION_COUNT_ELEMENTS" => "N",
        "SECTION_ID_VARIABLE" => "SECTION_ID",
        "SECTION_TOP_DEPTH" => "5",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/catalog/",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "SHOW_DEACTIVATED" => "Y",
        "SHOW_DISCOUNT_PERCENT" => "Y",
        "SHOW_EMPTY_STORE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_GENERAL_STORE_INFORMATION" => "N",
        "SHOW_LINK_TO_FORUM" => "Y",
        "SHOW_OLD_PRICE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_PRICE_COUNT" => "1",
        "SHOW_TOP_ELEMENTS" => "N",
        "SIDEBAR_DETAIL_SHOW" => "Y",
        "SIDEBAR_PATH" => "/catalog/sidebar.php",
        "SIDEBAR_SECTION_SHOW" => "Y",
        "STORES" => "",
        "STORE_PATH" => "/store/#store_id#",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "site",
        "TOP_ADD_TO_BASKET_ACTION" => "ADD",
        "URL_TEMPLATES_READ" => "",
        "USER_CONSENT" => "N",
        "USER_CONSENT_ID" => "0",
        "USER_CONSENT_IS_CHECKED" => "Y",
        "USER_CONSENT_IS_LOADED" => "N",
        "USER_FIELDS" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "USE_ALSO_BUY" => "N",
        "USE_BIG_DATA" => "N",
        "USE_CAPTCHA" => "Y",
        "USE_COMMON_SETTINGS_BASKET_POPUP" => "Y",
        "USE_COMPARE" => "N",
        "USE_ELEMENT_COUNTER" => "Y",
        "USE_FILTER" => "Y",
        "USE_GIFTS_DETAIL" => "Y",
        "USE_GIFTS_MAIN_PR_SECTION_LIST" => "Y",
        "USE_GIFTS_SECTION" => "Y",
        "USE_MAIN_ELEMENT_SECTION" => "N",
        "USE_MIN_AMOUNT" => "N",
        "USE_PRICE_COUNT" => "N",
        "USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY" => "Y",
        "USE_REVIEW" => "Y",
        "USE_SALE_BESTSELLERS" => "N",
        "USE_STORE" => "N",
        "USE_STORE_PHONE" => "Y",
        "USE_STORE_SCHEDULE" => "Y",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "sections" => "",
            "section" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/",
            "element" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
            "compare" => "compare/?action=COMPARE",
            "smart_filter" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/filter/#SMART_FILTER_PATH#/apply/",
        )
    ),
    false
);?
```

Answer (score 0):

В документации (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/catalog/catalog.php), сказано для отображения неактивных товаров должна быть установлена опция у компонента SHOW_DEACTIVATED => 'Y', наверно она не стоит у вас.

Comment: Действительно, SHOW_DEACTIVATED стояла в значении N, однако это ничего не изменило, но всё же спасибо за совет!

Comment: @Eduard возможно кеш нужно сбросить теперь, битрикса. Нужно в вопрос добавить код вызова компонента и то что в вашем фильтре, и информацию кастомный ли компонент или нет, тогда может что-то яснее будет.

Comment: @Eduard думаю, нужно убрать все параметры связанные с активностью (сортировка) и в массиве фильтра не указывать 'ACTIVE' вообще. И посмотрите ваш шаблон, он комплексный и внутри вызываются другие компоненты, нужно что бы SHOW_DEACTIVATED  дошёл до всех, просто может быть всё закостомлено так что параметры эти закомментированы. (А если не поможет уже зайти в файл component.php и смотреть как там выбираются товары в какой момент подкидывается 'ACTION' => 'Y', по какому условию )